# Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the Http Archive (HAR) from chrome via remote debugging?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, remote-debugging, har

From the network panel in a developer tools, a right click will allow "Copy all as HAR" or "Save as HAR with content" however I can't find a way to achieve that functionality programmatically. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Using the remote debugging functionality I can access information from the console, EG I can retrieve the timings for the page. Is there a command that would allow me to pull the entire HAR? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a node module that gets closest to what you want:

https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer

Note: This node module still has important unresolved timing issue. As an alternative, you can check this out:

https://github.com/parasdahal/speedprofile

Comment: Original question is about C#, not JS